# Flatten an array of objects containing key\values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects, key-value

Say I have the follow array of objects storing a single key\value pair:

```
var someArray = [
    {foo: 1},
    {bar: 2}
];
```

I would like to flatten this array into a single object, where each key from the original objects become a property of the new single object like so:

```
someObject = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
}
```

I will always have unique keys, and only ever one key\value pairing.

I know if I loop over the array in a foreach, then I can only access the index and value of the item, e.g.

```
0: {foo: 1}
```

I want to be able to loop over, and when accessing the item read the key and value separately so I can append onto my new object.

I feel like lodash should be able to help here, but I'm struggling to find whic of their methods could help.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get a new object with all properties.

```js
var someArray = [{ foo: 1 }, { bar: 2 }],
    result = someArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return Object.assign(r, a);
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

No need for lodash here you can just use `Object.assign()` and spread syntax.

```js
var someArray = [
  {foo: 1},
  {bar: 2}
];
var obj = Object.assign({}, ...someArray)
console.log(obj)
```

You can also use `apply` instead of spread syntax

```
var obj = Object.assign.apply({}, someArray)
```

```js
var someArray = [
  {foo: 1},
  {bar: 2}
];
var obj = Object.assign.apply({}, someArray)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: the logic on this changes a little when you have [ {foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 2: bar:2}].  You would end up with the second object.  Is it possible to adjust this logic to get all relationships into a single object?

Comment: Write desired output for this case.

Comment: {
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 1,
  "foo": 2, 
  "bar": 2 
 }

Comment: That is invalid result, you can't repeat keys.

Comment: {
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "test": 3, 
  "test2": 4 
 }

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quickly using `reduce` and `Object assign`:

```js
var someArray = [
    {foo: 1},
    {bar: 2}
];
var result = someArray.reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, obj), {})
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```