# How do I use the reduce method in loDash? Or Javascript Take a Array of Objects and Make one Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a Array of Objects:

```
` tempArray = [
      { name: 'Lion-O' },
      { gender: 'Male' },
      { weapon: 'Sword of Omens' },
      { status: 'Lord of the Thundercats' },
    ]
`
```

Object I want to Transform into:

```
`{
  name: 'Lion-O',
  gender: 'Male,',
  weapon: 'Sword of Omens',
  status: 'Lord of the Thundercats'
 }`
```

I tried to use reduce in LoDash;

```
const tempObj = _.reduce(tempArray, (r, v, k) => {        
    return r
})

console.log(tempObj);
//=> { name: 'Lion-O' }
```

I'm not sure how I should iterate over the Array? Looked at Doc's their example shows Adding or Pushing onto a Array .. I just want a Object.. I know it can be done. If their is a better way I'm open to that as well

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068529/flatten-an-array-of-objects-containing-key-values/42068621#42068621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 tempArray = [
      { name: 'Lion-O' },
      { gender: 'Male' },
      { weapon: 'Sword of Omens' },
      { status: 'Lord of the Thundercats' },
    ]
   
   var newObject = {};
   
   for (var index in tempArray) {
     thisObject = tempArray[index];
     for (var key in thisObject) { 
       newObject[key] = thisObject[key];
     }                      
   }
   
   console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter equivalent solution :

```
const tempArray = [
    { name: 'Lion-O' },
    { gender: 'Male' },
    { weapon: 'Sword of Omens' },
    { status: 'Lord of the Thundercats' },
];
const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...tempArray);
console.log(newObj);
// Object {name: "Lion-O", gender: "Male", weapon: "Sword of Omens", status: "Lord of the Thundercats"}
```